# Binning data in R

Tags: r, binning

I have a vector with around 4000 values. I would just need to bin it into 60 equal intervals for which I would then have to calculate the median (for each of the bins).

```
v<-c(1:4000)
```

V is really just a vector. I read about cut but that needs me to specify the breakpoints. I just want 60 equal intervals

Comment: Just a side note: you can write `v <- 1:4000`, no need for `c()` in that case.

Comment: 4000 doesn't divide equally by 60

Answer (score 18):

Use `cut` and `tapply`:

```
> tapply(v, cut(v, 60), median)
          (-3,67.7]          (67.7,134]           (134,201]           (201,268] 
               34.0               101.0               167.5               234.0 
          (268,334]           (334,401]           (401,468]           (468,534] 
              301.0               367.5               434.0               501.0 
          (534,601]           (601,668]           (668,734]           (734,801] 
              567.5               634.0               701.0               767.5 
          (801,867]           (867,934]         (934,1e+03]    (1e+03,1.07e+03] 
              834.0               901.0               967.5              1034.0 
(1.07e+03,1.13e+03]  (1.13e+03,1.2e+03]  (1.2e+03,1.27e+03] (1.27e+03,1.33e+03] 
             1101.0              1167.5              1234.0              1301.0 
 (1.33e+03,1.4e+03]  (1.4e+03,1.47e+03] (1.47e+03,1.53e+03]  (1.53e+03,1.6e+03] 
             1367.5              1434.0              1500.5              1567.0 
 (1.6e+03,1.67e+03] (1.67e+03,1.73e+03]  (1.73e+03,1.8e+03]  (1.8e+03,1.87e+03] 
             1634.0              1700.5              1767.0              1834.0 
(1.87e+03,1.93e+03]    (1.93e+03,2e+03]    (2e+03,2.07e+03] (2.07e+03,2.13e+03] 
             1900.5              1967.0              2034.0              2100.5 
 (2.13e+03,2.2e+03]  (2.2e+03,2.27e+03] (2.27e+03,2.33e+03]  (2.33e+03,2.4e+03] 
             2167.0              2234.0              2300.5              2367.0 
 (2.4e+03,2.47e+03] (2.47e+03,2.53e+03]  (2.53e+03,2.6e+03]  (2.6e+03,2.67e+03] 
             2434.0              2500.5              2567.0              2634.0 
(2.67e+03,2.73e+03]  (2.73e+03,2.8e+03]  (2.8e+03,2.87e+03] (2.87e+03,2.93e+03] 
             2700.5              2767.0              2833.5              2900.0 
   (2.93e+03,3e+03]    (3e+03,3.07e+03] (3.07e+03,3.13e+03]  (3.13e+03,3.2e+03] 
             2967.0              3033.5              3100.0              3167.0 
 (3.2e+03,3.27e+03] (3.27e+03,3.33e+03]  (3.33e+03,3.4e+03]  (3.4e+03,3.47e+03] 
             3233.5              3300.0              3367.0              3433.5 
(3.47e+03,3.53e+03]  (3.53e+03,3.6e+03]  (3.6e+03,3.67e+03] (3.67e+03,3.73e+03] 
             3500.0              3567.0              3633.5              3700.0 
 (3.73e+03,3.8e+03]  (3.8e+03,3.87e+03] (3.87e+03,3.93e+03]    (3.93e+03,4e+03] 
             3767.0              3833.5              3900.0              3967.0
```

Comment: +1 this is the simplest solution I always go with whenever binning data

Comment: how can the binned vector be plotted against the levels?

Comment: @morpheus Sorry, this is a really old answer for me, so I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 4):

In the past, i've used this function

```
evenbins <- function(x, bin.count=10, order=T) {
    bin.size <- rep(length(x) %/% bin.count, bin.count)
    bin.size <- bin.size + ifelse(1:bin.count <= length(x) %% bin.count, 1, 0)
    bin <- rep(1:bin.count, bin.size)
    if(order) {    
        bin <- bin[rank(x,ties.method="random")]
    }
    return(factor(bin, levels=1:bin.count, ordered=order))
}
```

and then i can run it with

```
v.bin <- evenbins(v, 60)
```

and check the sizes with

```
table(v.bin)
```

and see they all contain 66 or 67 elements. By default this will order the values just like `cut` will so each of the factor levels will have increasing values. If you want to bin them based on their original order,

```
v.bin <- evenbins(v, 60, order=F)
```

instead. This just split the data up in the order it appears

Comment: could you just briefly expand how I calculate the mean for each bin and then sore it in a seperate vector??

Comment: If you have a factor of bins, you would use `v.bin.means <- tapply(v, v.bin, mean)`

Comment: i do this for two vectors and have the vectors with the means (after the tapply step). They both have equal length and I would like to use 1 vector as x axis . I tried plot(vec1,vec2, type="l") but then I get multiple lines...

Comment: @user3419669 That sounds like a different problem. If you have a new question, you should start a different thread so others can as as well.

Answer (score 2):

This result shows the 59 median values of the break-points. The 60 bin values are probably as close to equal as possible (but probably not exactly equal).

```
> sq <- seq(1, 4000, length = 60)
> sapply(2:length(sq), function(i) median(c(sq[i-1], sq[i])))
# [1]   34.88983  102.66949  170.44915  238.22881  306.00847  373.78814
# [7]  441.56780  509.34746  577.12712  644.90678  712.68644  780.46610
#  ......
```

Actually, after checking, the bins are pretty darn close to being equal.

```
> unique(diff(sq))
# [1] 67.77966 67.77966 67.77966
```